# get the mean value columns for incrementing rows in dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe:

```
DF_NBA.head(4)
```

[image]

I want to calculate the average like above for `MeanGScore`.
and its applicable for `n` number of rows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Could you expand you example data? With a input and expected output?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. the Input is HScore and I want to add new column name MeanGScore that has the value as above.  Its like getting the mean value incremental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
import pandas as pd

HScore=[110, 120, 100, 120]
df=pd.DataFrame(data=HScore, columns=['HScore'])
df['MeanGScore']=df['HScore'].expanding().mean()
```

Or, the "traditional" and slow way:

```
tempSum=0;
count=0;
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tempSum+=row['HScore'];
    count+=1;
    df.loc[index,'MeanGScore']=tempSum/count;
```